# How do I fix these errors in my awk programs

Tags: bash, awk

I have this awk code:

```
BEGIN {
valid_name[0] = "CEO"
valid_name[1] = "maffu"
valid_name[2] = "gerry"
valid_name[3] = "bob"
valid_name[4] = "cath"
valid_name[5] = "tom.tom.the.son.of.the.piper"
valid_name[6] = "Insuro_Corp"
valid_name[7] = "who-pays-the-piper"
valid_name[8] = "a_hat_at_a_party"
valid_name[9] = "do_dot_the_eyes"
valid_name[10]= "Kim_dot_COM"

valid_domain[0] = "InsuroCorp"
valid_domain[1] = "cs.otago"
valid_domain[2] = "gmail"
valid_domain[3] = "enron"
valid_domain[4] = "research.techies"
valid_domain[5] = "1st.national"

valid_extension[0] = "co.nz"
valid_extension[1] = "com.au"
valid_extension[2] = "co.uk"
valid_extension[3] = "co.us"
valid_extension[4] = "co.ca"
valid_extension[5] = "com"

valid_numeric[0] = "[139.80.81.50]"
valid_numeric[1] = "[127.0.0.0]"
valid_numeric[2] = "[139.80.32.68]"
valid_numeric[3] = "[255.255.25.255]"

invalid_name[0] = "-foo"
invalid_name[1] = "f--d"
invalid_name[2] = "_at_"
invalid_name[3] = "Top$"
invalid_name[4] = "tom/tom"
invalid_name[5] = ".com.au"
invalid_name[6] = "white space"
invalid_name[7] = "  white-space"

invalid_domain[0] = "Insuro-Corp"
invalid_domain[1] = "cs_otago"
invalid_domain[3] = "100%"
invalid_domain[4] = "AT&T"

invalid_extension[0] = "ac.nz"
invalid_extension[1] = "edu.au"
invalid_extension[2] = "tv"
invalid_extension[3] = "com.us"
invalid_extension[4] = "edu"

invalid_numeric[0] = "139.80.81.50"
invalid_numeric[1] = "[1..2]"
invalid_numeric[2] = "[139-80-81-50]"
invalid_numeric[3] = "[1][2][3]"
}

function generate_invalid_e_mail_address() {
at = rand() < 0.3 ? "_at_" : rand() < 0.1 ? "" : "@"
dot = dot = rand() < 0.3 ? "_dot_" : rand() < 0.1 ? "" : "."
if (rand() < 0.5) {
    name = valid_name[int(rand()*11)]
    if (rand() < 0.3) {
        numeric = invalid_numeric[int(rand()*4)]
        print name at numeric
    } else {
        if (rand() < 0.5) {
            domain = valid_domain[int(rand()*6)]
            extension = invalid_extension[int(rand()*5)]
        } else {
            domain = invalid_domain[int(rand()*5)]
            extension = valid_extension[int(rand()*6)]
        }
        print name at domain dot extension
    }
} else {
    name = invalid_name[int(rand()*8)]
    if (rand() < 0.3) {
        numeric = valid_numeric[int(rand()*4)]
        print name at numeric
    } else {
        domain = valid_domain[int(rand()*5)]
        extension = valid_extension[int(rand()*6)]
        print name at domain dot extension
    }
}
}

BEGIN {
print "maffu@cs.otago.ac.nz"
print "bob.gmail.com"
for (i = 0; i < 518; i++) generate_invalid_e_mail_address()
}
```

This program should generate email address test cases and put
them in a file called 'bad.data' with the command:

```
awk -f bad.awk >bad.data
```

Instead bad.data is created as an empty file because of these
errors:

```
awk: bad.awk:70:                 extension = invalid_extension[int(rand()*5)]
awk: bad.awk:70:                           ^ syntax error
awk: bad.awk:73:                 extension = valid_extension[int(rand()*6)]
awk: bad.awk:73:                           ^ syntax error
awk: bad.awk:76:             print name at domain dot extension
awk: bad.awk:76:                                               ^ unexpected newline or end of string

awk: bad.awk:84:             extension = valid_extension[int(rand()*6)]
awk: bad.awk:84:                       ^ syntax error
awk: bad.awk:86:             print name at domain dot extension
awk: bad.awk:86:                                               ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

This is the first awk code I have seen. How do I fix it?

Comment: What version of `awk` are you running, and on what OS? I just ran it on my system and it works fine.

Comment: You can read the array initializations from some input files for readability.

Comment: Not your issue but FYI: awk arrays by convention (and generated by all builtin functions) start at 1, not 0. Also, rather than explicitly populating sequential elements of an array, all you need to do is use `split` on a string, e.g. `split("CEO maffu gerry",valid_name)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `extension` is a keyword. Just replace all `extension`s to `extension1` for example:

```
extension1 = invalid_extension[int(rand()*5)];
```

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{extension=4; print extension}'` prints `4` without any error on OSX.

Comment: That gives me syntax error too, for some reason `(GNU Awk 4.1.0)`.

Comment: Yes you're right this is gnu-awk issue. I just tried it on Linux and got `syntax error`. +1

Comment: +1: Or may be use `awk --posix -f bad.awk`. The script doesn't appear to use any `GNU` features anyway.

Comment: @user2689066 Please consider marking the answer correct by accepting it. You can do so by clicking the tick mark next to it so that it is green.